# Why are window shutters "persianas"?

Tags: etimología

Why are window shutters called "persianas" in Spanish?

If window shutters originated in Persia/Iran, I can find no evidence of that.

Comment: Persianas were used lot time ago in Egypt (made of reeds) and China (made of bamboo). I don't know what's the first origin of the item, but about the spanish word it is as I answered.

Comment: In English, they are called Venetian blinds. Funny, huh?

Comment: https://www.blindinglyobvious.co.uk/latest-news/venetian-blind-history

Comment: @Lambie: venetian blinds = persiana veneciana (https://dle.rae.es/persiana?m=form2#D5PHUFw)

Comment: No, window shutters are **not** persianas. Window shutters are contreventanas. https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraventana Y se ve en google que dicen shutters=persianas y es un **error** de traducción.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ESPAÑOL (English follows)

La palabra persiana, proviene del francés *persienne*. En el siglo XVIII, en Francia se puso de moda, entre otros muchos artículos orientales, una celosía de tablillas que podían enrollarse para regular la entrada de luz a las viviendas; se situaba entre la ventana y la contraventana o postigo. El artículo era algo nuevo, y necesitaba de un nombre; los comerciantes decidieron llamarlo según su procedencia (de Persia). Cuando llegó a España, en lugar de utilizar el término *persa* que equivale a procedente de Persia, se castellanizó como *persiana*.

---

ENGLISH

*Persiana* (roller blind) comes from the French word *persienne*. In the XVIII century, in France it became fashionable, among many other oriental items, a lattice of slats that could be rolled up to regulate the entry of light to homes; It was placed between the window and the shutters. The article was something new, and needed a name; traders decided to name it by its source (from Persia). When it arrived to Spain, instead of using the equivalent term *persa* (de Persia), it was converted to Spanish as *persiana*.

Comment: venetian blinds, in English.

Comment: I would not try and translate that into English. It does do the text justice....

Comment: @Lambie: venetian blinds = persiana veneciana (https://dle.rae.es/persiana?m=form2#D5PHUFw),

Comment: En español, se suele decir las persianas en el lenguaje cotidiano y no las persianas venecianas. And it is not placed "between the window and the shutters". Blinds go on the inside of a window and shutters (contreventanas) go on the outside. [arrived in Spain, not to Spain]